# What does the \the\everypar do?

Tags: tex-core

If you test the following minimal it does not produce an error. What does it actually do?

```
\the\everypar
\bye
```

Why doesn't it produce an error as one would expect?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`\everypar` is a token list register, so its value is assigned by

```
\everypar={<tokens>}
```

Its default value in Plain TeX is empty.

What's for? Its contents is delivered into the token list TeX is reading when it switches from vertical to horizontal mode. This happens when TeX, in vertical mode, sees a *horizontal command*, for instance a character to be typeset or `\indent` or `\noindent`.

At that time the horizontal command is set aside; before examining it again, TeX contributes `\parskip` glue to the vertical list and goes into horizontal mode; now it delivers the contents of `\everypar` as if `\the\everypar` was implicit and reexamines the horizontal command that forced the switch to horizontal mode. However the switching to horizontal mode caused by a horizontal command other than `\noindent` causes TeX to insert an empty box of width `\parindent` *before* the contents of `\everypar`.

One can use `\everypar` to perform automatically some job at paragraph start, for example to number them.

LaTeX exploits heavily this mechanism, so it's not recommended to play with it when the job involves lists. An example is the declaration

```
\everypar{\@nodocument}
```

that is in force until `\begin{document}` is processed; `\@nodocument` issues the error message `Missing \begin{document}` in order to warn the user that text starting a paragraph has been found in the preamble.

As all token registers, its value can be augmented by

```
\everypar=\expandafter{\the\everypar<tokens>}
```

since `\the\everypar` will deliver the current register's contents.

Comment: I want to add, there are other tokens like `\everymath`, `\everycr`, `\everydisplay`, `\everyvbox`, `\everyhbox`