# Numbers in bibliography and bullets in the list are not on the same line as text

Tags: bibliographies, lists

I have a problem with horizontal alignment in bibliography same as in the list or enumerate, see pictures.

[image]

[image]

My code in the both cases (the preambule is the same):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\everypar{\parindent=1cm}
\catcode`\"=\active
\def"{\bgroup \quotedblbase \def"{\textquotedblleft \egroup}}
\definecolor{sedive_pozadi}{gray}{0.7}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents    
\maketitle
```

blabla

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item text
    \item text
\end{itemize}

\begin{thebibliography}{100}
\bibitem{LPKP}Ludwig, Petr \textit{Konec prokrastinace: [Jak přestat        odkládat a začít žít naplno]}, V Brně: Jan Melvil, 2013, ISBN: 978-80-  87270-51-6.
\bibitem{PPJDZ}PRAŽÁK, Petr \textit{Jak dosáhnout změny: [Vykročte z komfortní zóny do zóny osobního rozvoje]}, [online] In:2016, 28.4.2016     [cit. 2020-02-28]. Dostupné z: https://psychologie.cz/jak-dosahnout-zmeny/
\bibitem{JJKZ}Jonáš, Josef \textit{Křížovka života: [Moudrost oreintální medicíny a dnešek]}, 3. vydání, V Litvínově: Dialog, 1990, ISBN: 80-85194-03-1.
\end{thebibliography}
```

Please, how to fix it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem, i.e. a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: The problem is `\def\everypar{\parindent=1cm}`. I'm not sure what that code was intended for, but I would try to avoid `\everypar` if at all possible. In any case `\everypar` is not something you can (or should) `\def`. You can read a bit about it in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33849/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119758/35864

Comment: Yeah, without everypar the problem was solved but it was useful "code" which I found on google :) (I'm not really good in latex code but I like it :)) for indentation of first raw of new paragraph after title. I'm going to read recommended links. Thanks.